# Как поставить mcrypt для версии 8*-fpm?

Tags: php, docker

Решил обновить в docker-compose версию php с 7.4 на 8.2. Ругается на 2 строчки:

> && pecl install mcrypt-1.0.3
> && docker-php-ext-enable mcrypt

В версии 7.4 все работает. Как установить mcrypt в 8 версии?
Вот мой конфиг:

```
FROM php:8.2-fpm
# ставим необходимые для нормальной работы модули
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y
        curl
        wget
        git
        libfreetype6-dev
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev
    libpng-dev
    libonig-dev
    libzip-dev
    libmcrypt-dev
        && pecl install mcrypt-1.0.3
    && docker-php-ext-enable mcrypt
        && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mbstring mysqli pdo_mysql zip
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg
        && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd 
# Устанавливаем Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
WORKDIR /data
VOLUME /data
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Comment: Посмотреть [список поддерживаемых версий](https://pecl.php.net/package/mcrypt) и заменить 1.0.3 на 1.0.6 например?

Comment: А лучше вообще выкинуть mcrypt, потому что в документации давно написано, что он устарел, и заменить его на какой-нибудь openssl или типа того

Comment: Получилось! Заменил 1.0.3 на 1.0.6 и все ок! Хотя раньше пробовал 1.0.4 и 1.0.5 - не работало . Спасибо Всем за участие и andreymal за решение!